# Debugging code with Plot function. Full details

Tags: plotting, fourier-analysis, core-language

This is some code:
The first plot (with the f[x,3]) gives me a graph.
The second plot (with the 'numerical' form of f[x,3] given) does give me a plot

How can I fix this so that the first line gives me a plot?

```
f[x_, Nmax_] := 
 Sum[a[n] Cos[24.30538589` n x], {n, 1, Nmax}] + 
  Sum[b[n] Sin[24.30538589` n x], {n, 1, Nmax}] + a[0]/2;


f[x, 3]
(*-0.000663106 - 0.0216591 Cos[24.3054 x] - 0.00475935 Cos[48.6108 x] - 
 0.00889405 Cos[72.9162 x] + 0.0129294 Sin[24.3054 x] - 
 0.0228661 Sin[48.6108 x] + 0.00536402 Sin[72.9162 x]*)

Plot[{f[x, 3]}}, {x, 0.30383`, 0.56234`}]

Plot[{{-0.0006631064575023214` - 
    0.02165905118857869` Cos[24.30538589` x] - 
    0.004759352355590257` Cos[48.61077178` x] - 
    0.008894049060596227` Cos[72.91615767` x] + 
    0.012929362498750253` Sin[24.30538589` x] - 
    0.0228661379875381` Sin[48.61077178` x] + 
    0.005364020800842659` Sin[72.91615767` x]}}, {x, 0.30383`, 
  0.56234`}]
```

**EDIT**

[image]

**EDIT 2**

Below is the entire code that I have written: Note that I have given just the inputs and not the outputs, but everything up until the second plot does actually seem to work and give me something which seems right...

```
data = {{0.30383`, -0.06683`}, {0.30837`, -0.05289`}, {0.3129`, \
-0.01927`}, {0.31744`, 0.02776`}, {0.32197`, 0.07177`}, {0.32651`, 
   0.08597`}, {0.33104`, 0.06693`}, {0.33558`, 0.03273`}, {0.34011`, 
   0.01049`}, {0.34465`, -0.00002`}, {0.34918`, 0.00341`}, {0.35372`, 
   0.01329`}, {0.35825`, 0.03038`}, {0.36279`, 0.04189`}, {0.36732`, 
   0.04932`}, {0.37186`, 0.05579`}, {0.37639`, 0.06438`}, {0.38093`, 
   0.05812`}, {0.38546`, 0.04418`}, {0.39`, 0.03288`}, {0.39454`, 
   0.01151`}, {0.39907`, -0.00437`}, {0.40361`, -0.02415`}, \
{0.40814`, -0.04318`}, {0.41268`, -0.04488`}, {0.41721`, -0.02499`}, \
{0.42175`, 0.00254`}, {0.42628`, 
   0.01371`}, {0.43082`, -0.00089`}, {0.43535`, -0.03078`}, \
{0.43989`, -0.06009`}, {0.44442`, -0.06483`}, {0.44896`, -0.04092`}, \
{0.45349`, -0.00142`}, {0.45803`, 0.03525`}, {0.46256`, 
   0.06063`}, {0.4671`, 0.05745`}, {0.47163`, 
   0.02872`}, {0.47617`, -0.01207`}, {0.4807`, -0.03938`}, {0.48524`, \
-0.04251`}, {0.48977`, -0.0247`}, {0.49431`, -0.009`}, {0.49884`, \
-0.00429`}, {0.50338`, -0.00654`}, {0.50791`, -0.01283`}, {0.51245`, \
-0.02396`}, {0.51698`, -0.04457`}, {0.52152`, -0.0575`}, {0.52605`, \
-0.06183`}, {0.53059`, -0.04522`}, {0.53512`, -0.01328`}, {0.53966`, 
   0.01694`}, {0.5442`, 0.0262`}, {0.54873`, 
   0.00785`}, {0.55327`, -0.03305`}, {0.5578`, -0.07145`}, {0.56234`, \
-0.07393`}}
ListPlot[data, Joined -> True, Epilog -> {Black, Point[data]}]
ListPlot[data, Joined -> True]
nn = Length@data
fun = Interpolation[data]
{x1, x2} = fun[[1, 1]]
Plot[fun[x], {x, x1, x2}, Epilog -> {Black, Point[data]}]
NIntegrate[fun[x] Cos[x], {x, x1, x2}]
a[n_?NumericQ] := 
 NIntegrate[
  7.7366446172295085*fun[x]*Cos[7.7366446172295085*Pi*n x], {x, x1, 
   x2}]
7.7366446172295085*Integrate[fun[x] Cos[24.30538589 n x], {x, x1, x2}]
b[n_?NumericQ] := 
 NIntegrate[
  7.7366446172295085*fun[x]*Sin[7.7366446172295085*Pi*n x], {x, x1, 
   x2}]
Sum[a[n] Cos[24.30538589` n x], {n, 1, 3}] + 
 Sum[b[n] Sin[24.30538589` n x], {n, 1, 3}] + a[0]/2
f[x_, Nmax_] := 
 Sum[a[n] Cos[24.30538589` n x], {n, 1, Nmax}] + 
  Sum[b[n] Sin[24.30538589` n x], {n, 1, Nmax}] + a[0]/2
f[x, 3]
Plot[{{-0.0006631064575023214` - 
    0.02165905118857869` Cos[24.30538589` x] - 
    0.004759352355590257` Cos[48.61077178` x] - 
    0.008894049060596227` Cos[72.91615767` x] + 
    0.012929362498750253` Sin[24.30538589` x] - 
    0.0228661379875381` Sin[48.61077178` x] + 
    0.005364020800842659` Sin[72.91615767` x]}}, {x, 0.30383`, 
  0.56234`}]
Plot[f[x, 3], {x, 0.3083, 0.56234}]
```

Comment: What are `a` and `b`?

Comment: @MelaGo - a[n] and b[n] are Fourier coefficients.

Comment: You have an extra curly brace in the first `Plot` that you need to remove. Actually, even `Plot[f[x,3], {x, 0.3083, 0.56234}]` should be fine.

Comment: @MassDefect - that's what I thought! But if you look at the edit above, I have added a screenshot - this still gives me no plot...Why!?

Comment: Now can you provide how you define $a$ and $b$? I suspect that's where the issue will arise. In general, please provide a minimal working example, i.e. we can copy and paste your code into our own Mathematica and reproduce your issue.

Comment: @bRost03 - ok, standby, just adding the information into the question now.

Comment: In your screenshot, `f` is blue, which means you didn't evaluate it yet...

Comment: As for the last point - how do I evaluate f then?

Comment: @bRost03 - code added.

Comment: @Rushi hit shift+enter?

Comment: Yes, that's what I am doing! (after the last line of code)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are doing way! too much work in your code. The way it is set up, every time you evaluate `f` it reevaluates `a` and `b` which makes your code super slow. I suspect this is your issue, Mathematica will eventually produce the graph you desire - but it takes so long you say "it gives me no plot". I gave up on letting your code run after a minute or so.

Let's try to make the code a bit more efficient. You can tell Mathematica to store the expressions for `a[n]` and `b[n]` by doing the following (I named your constants because I hate to see wild numbers floating around in code)

```
c1 = 7.7366446172295085;
c2 = 24.30538589;
a[n_?NumericQ] := a[n] = NIntegrate[c1*fun[x]*Cos[c1*Pi*n x], {x, x1, x2}]
b[n_?NumericQ] := b[n] = NIntegrate[c1*fun[x]*Sin[c1*Pi*n x], {x, x1, x2}]
f[x_, Nmax_] := Sum[a[n] Cos[c2 n x], {n, 1, Nmax}] + 
     Sum[b[n] Sin[c2 n x], {n, 1, Nmax}] + a[0]/2
```

Notice the construction `a[n_]:=a[n]=...`? This tells Mathematica that when e.g. `a[3]` is calculated the first time - store that result so next time `a[3]` is used it just returns the stored value instead of recomputing it. Making this change

```
Plot[f[x, 3], {x, 0.3083, 0.56234}]
```

runs in a snap.

### EDIT

OP said she wanted to make a `Manipulate` where `Nmax` varied. In this case I recommend directly storing `f` as well as `a` and `b` to avoid redoing the `Sum`s. This runs very quickly on my machine

```
f[Nmax_] := f[Nmax] = Sum[a[n] Cos[c2 n #], {n, 1, Nmax}] + 
     Sum[b[n] Sin[c2 n #], {n, 1, Nmax}] + a[0]/2 &;
Table[f[M][1], {M, 50}] (* run to store everything before trying to plot *)
Manipulate[Plot[f[M][x], {x, 0.3083, 0.56234}], {M, 1, 50, 1}]
```

Comment: You are a genius @bRost03! And if I change the value I for Nmax e.g. I change it to 4 then 5 then 6 etc will I need to add any code?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VF1tOcEVGyU
I essentially want to do something like this and have a slider like he does at the end

Comment: @Rushi no, this should work fine for any `Nmax`. If `Nmax` gets very large - there are likely more optimizations that can be done.

Comment: No I don't intend anything too large. Actually maybe 50 is quite large?